# Running Spark job locally with HiveContext throwing error

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-14, hivecontext

I am running spark jobs locally for debugging purpose. I have imported spark-core jar file using sbt. I am using hiveContext in my code. It is throwing following error. 
   **The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-**

Once again, I have not installed spark or hadoop on my local machine. I am importing all the jars using sbt and running them in Intellij. Is there any way I can fix that.

Thanks,